# Remote control Windows 10 Pro laptop in backpack from Android phone without internet, but Bluetooth or WiFi

Tags: android, windows-10, offline, remote-desktop, bluetooth

I travel a lot in my town on foot and via bus/train/tram and it's winter. Therefore, I have no time or space or way to take out my laptop until I'm sitting somewhere. I was thinking if I could access my laptop from my Android phone while my laptop is in my backpack, but WITHOUT using the internet. Many apps have ads and require me to have internet access which is pointless since my laptop and phone are at close proximity. It would also require a huge dataplan for which I have no money to pay. And when I'm traveling via train through rural areas, the internet connection is very weak. And even if those weren't an issue, I still don't really feel comfortable with transfering my personal data over the internet when I can just access it over Bluetooth or WiFi.

Is there an app that could let me access my laptop via my Android phone, but in a way that involves only Bluetooth or WiFi without using the internet?

My laptop is HP Elitebook 840 G1 refurbished with Windows 10 Pro and is very strong, but my Android phone is a Huawei Honor 7 Lite with Android 7.0 which has its problems like shutting down things if the screen goes black and restarting my apps if I switch them.

The app needs to have these features:

- Zooming in and out the "virtual camera" of my phone on the laptop's screen without interfering with the zooming of the laptop (as Opera/Chrome and other browsers would do)
- Using an in-app keyboard for typing. It needs to have a QWERTZ Croatian keyboard with all the keys available. Yes, all! Home, end, print screen, insert, delete, fn shortcuts, all which you could find on a Windows XP computer!
- Touchpad-like mouse control with left and right click and drag possible without double-tap combo combinations or other crazy things.
- No shutting down if the app loses focus to a phonecall, alarm or switching between applications
- If the app uses Bluetooth, it would be good that it has WiFi tethering from my phone to my laptop over Bluetooth
- Sound should not play on my laptop nor should my laptop's microphone be used. Instead, things should go to my phone's speaker, earphone, headphones, headset, microphone, all depending on customizable settings.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1) time of r anew 'phone 2) won't your laptop sleep if you close its lid? Or do you plan to have it open inside your backpack? Perhaps a cheap tablet is the answer, suing your 'phone as a WiFi hotpsot?

Comment: My laptop can run well with its lid closed. I turned off the setting to put the laptop to sleep when the lid is closed. But still, your comment doesn't answer my question. I asked if there's an app to do what I have pointed out in my post.

Comment: Interesting. I never thought to try that. Sorry that my comment doesn't answer your question - that's why I didn't post an answer ;-) If you want to remotely run Windows programs on your laptop, controlled by your 'phone. then get a VNC (Virtual Network Controller). It sounds, though, like you (also) nee a new 'phone. In fact, a cheap tablet might be better, given the screen size.

Comment: I used TeamViewer on even older phones and it worked well. I think VNC should work well. I just don't know if it's possible to do without internet connection, but with only connecting my phone with my laptop via Bluetooth or by having one of them have a WiFi hotspot. But WiFi could be a problem. My phone cannot connect to an external hotspot while being connected to my laptop. Connecting my laptop AND phone on a foreign hotspot seems like a serious security risk. That's why I'd prefer to stay on Bluetooth. Is that a possible solution?

Comment: "phone cannot connect to an external hotspot while being connected to my laptop" Your laptop (client) is connected to your phone (server), which as client is connected to another free wifi (server). Should be no problem at all

Comment: Phone cannot be both WiFi client and WiFi server. That's the issue. I have Huawei Honor 7 Lite. If my laptop and phone used Bluetooth for VNC and WiFi for the internet connection, then that would be a better option. The point is that the VNC connection MUST NOT be online or via foreign WiFi network because it's either a dataplan cost or a security risk.

Comment: One question. Aren't you risking a fire by keeping the laptop turned on in a closed backpack? The machine can get really hot inside.

Comment: Not if I have a USB laptop cooler and if it's really cold outside. Anyways, I cannot find a solution for having a VNC connection over Bluetooth. Maybe I need multiple solutions at the same time, but I don't want to bloat my laptop and phone with junk software while trying out what works and what doesn't. That's why I'm asking here if someone has succeeded in making a solution.

Comment: You might wish to take a look at my app listing [Remote Droid 1: Control your Computer using your Droid](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controlpc). The in-app keyboard might get tricky, but I guess a VNC solution should cover that.